# Difference between Action() and RenderAction()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc2, what's the difference between

```
Html.Action(...)
```

and

```
Html.RenderAction(...)
```

?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Phil Haack does a great job explaining the two methods in [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

"The difference between the two is that Html.RenderAction will render the result directly to the Response (which is more efficient if the action returns a large amount of HTML) whereas Html.Action returns a string with the result."

Comment: Somehow missed that post. Thanks.